# calculating total number in text file separate with comma

Tags: python, file

I have this data in txt file:

```
1,2,3,4
```

How do I calculate the average from it? This is what I have so far but it print
**invalid literal for int() with base 10** :

```
data = []
with open('number.txt') as x:
    for line in x:
        y = line.split()
        xdata = map(int,y)
        data.extend(xdata)
    print('Total:',sum(data))
    print('Average:',(sum(data)/len(data)))
```

Suggestion and help please.Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the changed code as you can see we need to split with comma so that it works properly

```
data = []
with open('number.txt') as x:
    for line in x:
        y = line.split(',')
        xdata = map(int,y)
        data.extend(xdata)
    print('Total:',sum(data))
    print('Average:',(sum(data)/len(data)))
```

you can learn more about split on [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm)

Answer (score 2):

If you're splitting by comma, you'll need to specify that delimiter to `split`:

```
>>> line.split(',')
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

Otherwise, you split by space by default, meaning `y` becomes

```
>>> line.split()
['1,2,3,4']
```

Which is an invalid numeric value, raising the error.

---

You can consolidate your code with a list comprehension:

```
with open('number.txt') as f:
    data = [int(x) for line in f for x in line.split(',')]

avg = sum(data) / len(data)
```

Comment: @Joehan If it works, you could mark the answer accepted. Cheers! Edit: Ah, I see you marked another answer. No probs.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a list of integers from the string you read from the file like this:

```
from ast import literal_eval
Your_list=literal_eval(your_string)
Your_integer_list=[]
for i in Your_list:
    Your_integer_list.append(int(i))
```

Comment: This works, however, the last 3 lines are redundant. `literal_eval()` already returns a _tuple_ of integers so you don't need to convert with `int()`. And you could use `list.extend()` to accumulate the integers from each line of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a solution.

You can open the file using the csv module:

```
import csv


with open("yourfile.txt") as csv_file:
    data = [int(x) for x in csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')[0]]

print sum(data)
print sum(data)/len(data)
```

The `[0]` index is to get the first line in your file
and i used a [list comprehension](https://www.python-course.eu/list_comprehension.php) to get the values as integers

[more about csv files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)

[more about the csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [@Karak's effort](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47054314/21945) with [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) consider this:

```
from ast import literal_eval
from statistics import mean

with open('number.txt') as f:
    data = [i for line in f for i in literal_eval(line)]

    print('Total:', sum(data))
    print('Average:', mean(data))
```

This will work as long as the file contains comma separated numbers (will also work with floats, and mixed floats and ints). If there is a single number on a line it must have a trailing `,` so `literal_eval()` will interpret the line as a tuple.